# Creating a scrollspy manually in Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, scrollspy

I have set up scrollspy inside a `MatDialog`, and the event `activate.bs.scrollspy` doesn't seem to fire, or maybe it does fire, but probably at a window level, and it doesn't highlight the anchors on my navbar, as I scroll down. I'm using Angular 17 and bootstrap 5.3.

```
<div id="scrollContainer" class="row">
    <nav id="scrollspy-navbar" class="col-4 navbar-light flex-column align-items-stretch pe-4 border-end overflow-auto">
        <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#item-01">{{heading01}}</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#item-02">{{heading02}}</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#item-03">{{heading03}}</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#item-04">{{heading04}}</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#item-05">{{heading05}}</a>
        </nav>
    </nav>

    <div id="scrollspy-panel" 
         class="col-8 px-3" 
         data-bs-spy="scroll" 
         data-bs-target="#scrollspy-navbar" 
         data-bs-smooth-scroll="true" 
         tabindex="0">
        <div id="item-01">
            <p>...</p>
        <div id="item-02">
            <p>...</p>
        <div id="item-03">
            <p>...</p>
        <div id="item-04">
            <p>...</p>
        <div id="item-05">
            <p>...</p>
```

My css

```
#scrollspy-navbar {
    height: 60vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#scrollspy-panel {
    height: 60vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I have tried to listen to `activate.bs.scrollspy` without using jquery, as it's considered bad practice in the latest versions of Angular. I tried using `@HostListener` but I don't think I can catch `activate.bs.scrollspy` with that.

I've also tried

```
    <div id="scrollspy-panel" 
         class="col-8 px-3" 
         data-bs-spy="scroll" 
         data-bs-target="#scrollspy-navbar" 
         data-bs-smooth-scroll="true" 
         tabindex="0" 
         (scroll)="onPanelScroll($event)">
```

and then

```
  onPanelScroll (e:any):void {
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
  }
```

but it logs the entire `<div id="scrollspy-panel">` itself, and not the particular `<div id="item-0X">` item on display.

I read that in bootstrap 5.3 I'm supposed to capture `e.relatedTarget` on `activate.bs.scrollspy` but I've no idea how to do that without using jquery.

Is there a way I can

- make scrollspy work inside a dialog box,
- or set up scrollspy manually from scratch,
- or listen to `activate.bs.scrollspy` without using jquery?

If anyone could help me in any of these ways or with any other useful suggestions, or respond in a friendly way without causing offence, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/scrollspy/src) an example, [here's](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/app/pages/advanced/scrollspy) how to use it, and [here's](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/advanced/scrollspy) a demo

Comment: Oh, wow! Thanks so much for this!! Unfortunately I tried it and it works like a charm at page level, but insde a `MatDialog` popup it does not :((  I still learnt a lot from the code and demo!

Answer (score 0):

In the component, instantiate scroll spy [with JavaScript](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/scrollspy/#via-javascript) instead, as it seems that data attributes don't work well with dynamically added content.

Try this (remove data attributes from template HTML):

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const scrollSpy = new bootstrap.ScrollSpy('#scrollspy-panel', {
      target: '#scrollspy-navbar'
    });
  }
```